# Do apport core dumps contain sensitive information?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, core-dump

For example, if I am drafting an email in a text editor, the text editor crashes, and apport creates a file in /var/crash, will the data below "CoreDump: base64" contain a copy of that draft? Could it also contain text that has been typed in other running programs? I did a base64 to base8 conversion on the data block, but the only string I have been able so far is "CoreDump" at the top line.

I have not been able to find another question regarding this, so can someone please enlighten me on what *isn't* inside a core dump versus the usual what is? Thank you very much!

Comment: See also [How confidential are automatic crash reports made by apport?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/383722/how-confidential-are-automatic-crash-reports-made-by-apport)

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, core dumps *may* contain sensitive information. A core dump is basically showing you the contents of the memory of the problem process at the moment of the crash. For more info on how to read a core dump please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_dump .

Comment: Is this base64 core dump containing potentially sensitive information sent when filing a bug report with the "Report a problem" window? Thank you for your answer. :)

Comment: The core dump is only related to the process that crashed, not what happens afterwards.

Comment: I mean in situations like this: http://kephost.com/images/2016/05/20/Screenshotfrom2016-05-2007-37-23.png